# Setup dynamic routing in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

I am facing some issue while setting up the routing in the angular 8.
I am doing it like:

```
'company/:id/activity'
'company/:id/contacts'
```

did not get any params in  activatedRoute:

```
this.activateRoute.params
            .subscribe(param => console.log(param) )
```

Is there any luck to fix that?

Main Routing file:

```
{
                path: 'company/:id',
                children: [
                    {
                        path: '',
                        loadChildren: () => import('@app/features/company-view/company-view.module').then(m => m.CompanyViewModule)
                    }
                ]
            }
```

Lazy loaded routing file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { CompanyViewComponent } from '@app/features/company-view/company-view.component';
import { PendingChangesGuard } from '@app/shared/guards';
import { CompanyActivityComponent } from './company-activity/company-activity.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: CompanyViewComponent,
    children: [
      { 
        path: '', 
        redirectTo: 'view'
      },
      {
        path: 'activity',
        component: CompanyActivityComponent,
        data: {
          title: "Company Activity"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class CompanyViewRoutingModule { }
```

if I use routing below then it works fine:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: CompanyViewComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: ':id/activity',
        component: CompanyActivityComponent,
        data: {
          title: "Company Activity"
        }
      },
      {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: 'activity'
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

then how do I set the default routing to `:id/activity` ?

Comment: what is the result of console.log(param)?

Comment: Hello there. Can you include your entire route file / routing module that shows all your routes?

Comment: @robbieAreBest it is empty object

Comment: @DamianC added in the question

Comment: @MaihanNijat yes it is same

Comment: Can you share the entire component code for where you call activatedRoute?

Answer (score 1):

So. You want to pass variables for your component through the routing.
In your routes.ts is oke like this `path: 'company/:id/:activity'`.
Then you need to give it to your component. 
I'm using this: `id = this.route.snapshot.params['id']` or `activity = this.route.snapshot.params['activity']`.
From here you can pass through for another component or whatever you want.

Ex:

```
<app-testcomponent
    [id]="id"
    [activity]="activity">
</app-testcomponent>
```

Comment: I am not using :activity like that activity is static text

Comment: That's okay. company/:id/activity and
id = this.route.snapshot.params['id']

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing a route for this: "view".

```
  { 
    path: '', 
    redirectTo: 'view'
  }
```

I changed it to "activity" and changed it to your catch all route for that section of the tree. I also refactored your routes a little bit, please look at both:

Main Route

```
{
    path: 'company',
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: () => import('@app/features/company-view/company-view.module').then(m => m.CompanyViewModule)
        }
    ]
}
```

Child Routes

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':id',
    component: CompanyViewComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'activity',
        component: CompanyActivityComponent,
        data: {
          title: "Company Activity"
        }
      },
      { 
        path: '**', 
        redirectTo: 'activity'
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: redirect is fine, just not getting the params

Comment: if I am directly accessing: http://localhost:4200/company/647/activity
I can see the page properly but not getting the "647"

Comment: Did you try bumping the :id down to where I put it on the CompanyViewComponent?